# Selenium find Only non-hidden and non disabled items?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In python I wrote:

```
login_forms = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='form')
```

which works perfect for getting all forms in page. Then I iterate over all inputs in form like this:

```
form_inputs = login_forms[0].find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='input')
```

How can I find only items which are not hidden or disabled (those which normal user can see and tamper or right his own value inside)?

---

Suggested code (which didn't work for me):

```
login_forms = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='form')


for login_form in login_forms:
        clean_form_inputs = login_form.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[not @disabled and(not(contains(@class,'disabled'))) and(not(contains(.,'display: none')))]")
        if len(clean_form_inputs) < 2:
            continue
        print(str(len(clean_form_inputs)))
```

I'm getting:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
> selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
> //*[not @disabled and(not(contains(@class,'disabled')))
> and(not(contains(.,'display: none')))] because of the following error:
> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
> '//*[not @disabled and(not(contains(@class,'disabled')))
> and(not(contains(.,'display: none')))]' is not a valid XPath
> expression.   (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.83)

Comment: Could you show some reproducible example?  [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go give you a correct answer we need to know how defined hidden and disabled blocks and elements.
I can assume that disabled element will have `disabled` attribute or `disabled` class name while hidden blocks will have `display: none` style value or `type="hidden"`.
If so, we can define the locator to locate all element that are not disabled and not hidden as following:

```py
"//*[not(@disabled) and(not(contains(@class,'disabled'))) and(not(contains(.,'display: none'))) and(not(@type='hidden'))]"
```

With Selenium `find_elements` it will look like:

```py
visible_enabled_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[not(@disabled) and(not(contains(@class,'disabled'))) and(not(contains(.,'display: none'))) and(not(@type='hidden'))]")
```

But this implementation depends on how exactly disabled and hidden elements on web site you are working on since it may differ.
**UPD**
There is no need to combine `By.XPATH` and `By.TAG_NAME` since `By.XPATH` already includes the element tag name.
In the example above I used `//*` to locate all tag names, but if you want to select `input` elements only for example it will be:

```py
visible_enabled_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[not(@disabled) and(not(contains(@class,'disabled'))) and(not(contains(.,'display: none'))) and(not(@type='hidden'))]")
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243234/discussion-on-answer-by-prophet-selenium-find-only-non-hidden-and-non-disabled-i).

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how the form is hidden or disabled:

1. is the form using specific class to enable or disable
2. Can css value be used to decide whether its hidden
3. Can isvisible and isEnabled inbuilt methods works etc , if so , find all elements then iterate through each element and filter the elements which give isvisible or isenabled as true

   print([element for element in driver.find_elements(*locator)
   if(element.is_displayed())])

see all available methods at :

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed